# Helper code runs mistakenly on page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method in one of my helpers which I want to run when a button is clicked on my page.
The problem is that whenever the page with the button loads, the method executes without any button click.

What can I do to stop it?
I have this method:

```
private
def add_like(item)  
a = current_user.exp + 50
current_user.update_attributes(exp: a)
b = item.likes + 1
item.update_attributes(likes: b)
end
```

the idea is of course to update some item likes and add points to the user.
but it happens corectly every load.

The view:

```
<fieldset style="height:200px;overflow:auto;">
<legend><h3>הזמנות אחרונות שלי</h3></legend>
<% current_user.orders.reverse[0..14].each do |o| %>
<%= o.food_item.likes %>
הזמנה - #<%= o.id %><br>
<% food = FoodItem.find(o.food_item) %>
<%= Provider.find(food.provider_id).name %><br>
תאריך הזמנה: <%= o.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %><br>
מחיר - <%= o.price %><br>
<%=  link_to image_tag("/images/like.jpg",size:"35x35"),"#", onclick:    add_like(o.food_item), :method => :put%>
<%=  link_to image_tag("/images/feedback.jpg",size:"75x75"),"#" %><br>
<br>
<%= image_tag(FoodItem.find(o.food_item).photo, size:"120x120") %>  
<% end  %>
</fieldset>
```

The link_to is the one at the six row before the end.

Comment: Please provide some code in order to help understand where the problem is

Comment: probably an issue with the code on your page as well - can you post that as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does exactly what expected : you're passing an arbitrary `onclick` option to the `link_to` method (onclick won't work as Ruby/Rails code is executed on the server side). As it is Ruby/Rails code (helpers expose methods available to views), it is executed **on the server side each time the page is rendered**. The value of this option is evaluated and the `add_like` method called, leading to a database update (`update_attributes` method actually performs a record update).

You can't run an helper method "on click" as helpers are available only when rendering the templates. Once the page has been rendered, it's up the client / browser to perform calls to the server. You should not call ActiveRecord create/update/destroy methods from views as this is the responsibility of controllers. Instead, your link should trigger a **client** call to a controller that would update the record.

As a good introduction to MVC you may check the Rails Guides, in particular [ActionController](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)-related documentation.